# How to assign type for axios response which is inside dispatch function. (React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, axios

Action function:

```
export const getOpportunityDetail =
  (opportunityId: string, userId?: string) => async (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "get",
        url: `${URL}${RoutingLinks.OPPORTUNITIES_DETAIL}/${opportunityId}?currentUserId=${userId}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (err: any) {
      dispatch<any>(handleError(err));
      return err.response;
    }
  };
```

getting data from backend

```
const result: any = await dispatch(
        getOpportunityDetail(locationState as string, userData._id)
      );
```

i want to give a type to result, how do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `: any` annotation from result and change `return response.data;` and `return err.response;` to `return response.data as ResponseType;` and `return err.response as ErrorType;`. Where `ResponseType` and `ErrorType` are appropriate types for your response.

You need to remove `any` since it basically "removes" type annotations from things it's applied to. You need to provide `as Type` by hand, since Typescript cannot know what shape data you receive from network (through axios) is - so you need to explicitly provide it.

In general for writing Typescript never use `any`, annotate functions that call external apis using `as` and rely on type inference for most things in between.